# printing variable after setting a bit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to set a bit in a 8 bit variable.
Every time I print the variable after setting a particular bit , I always get the value as 1.

```
uint8 value;
value = (1<<1 || value)
printf(%x \n,value); //prints 1 instead of 2
value = (1<<2 || value)
printf(%x \n,value); //prints 1 instead of 4
```

Comment: You need bitwise OR, not logical OR: `|` not `||`

Comment: Because of "||" is treated as boolean. Anything_but_zero OR Anything_but_zero is TRUE, and TRUE is 1.

Comment: @user996142 bitwise OR (`|`) and logical OR (`||`) both perform boolean OR operations... the difference is just what they perform them on (`|` on individual bit positions, `||` on the entire values)

Comment: `value` is also uninitialized.

Comment: @Dmitri: FYI, the standard differentiates between _bitwise_ and _logical_ (boolean) operators.

Comment: I agree. I probably used the wrong word. Actually, in case of ``||`` the *whole value* is treated as boolean, so any number except 0 is TRUE. And in case of bitwise OR each bit is treated as boolean. One can say addition is used.

Comment: @user996142 bitwise OR is quite different from addition... even without carry, addition is more like XOR.  `|` is only equiv. to `+` when only (at most) one of the values has a `1` in any given bit position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using boolean 'or' `||`. Bitwise 'or' is `|`.

Also you haven't initialized `value` so you can't expect it to be anything.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't do it like that.

To set a bit you OR with 1.

For example to set the least significant bit you OR with 1.

ie:

```
 unsigned char val = 4;
 // set bit 0
 val |= 1;
 printf("Value now: %x\n", val);
```

To set bit 1:

```
 unsigned char val = 4;
 // set bit 1
 val |= 1 << 1;
 printf("Value now: %x\n", val);
```

A complete example

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* get_binary(unsigned char buffer, char* binary) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        int bit = (buffer >> i) & 1;
        binary[7 - i] = bit ? '1' : '0';
    }
    return binary;
}


int main() {

    unsigned char val = 4;  // val now 100
    int bits_to_shift;
    unsigned char buffer[10] = { 0 };
    unsigned char* p = buffer;
    // set bit 0
    val |= 1;  
    printf("Value now: %x, binary=%s\n", val, get_binary(val, p));  // val now 5 :- 101

    // To set bit 1 (ie set so we have 111), shift to position then OR

    // set bit 1
    bits_to_shift = 1;
    val |= 1 << bits_to_shift;
    printf("Value now: %x, binary=%s\n", val, get_binary(val, p));  // val now 7 :- 111 

    // set bit 3
    bits_to_shift = 3;
    val |= 1 << bits_to_shift;
    printf("Value now: %x, binary=%s\n", val, get_binary(val, p));  // val now F :- 1111
}
```